# Why is this operator called in C++?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I dont understand, why is the aaa operator called in the 2nd last line?

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
private:
    typedef void (MyClass::*aaa)() const;
    void ThisTypeDoesNotSupportComparisons() const {}
public:
    operator aaa() const { return (true) ? &MyClass::ThisTypeDoesNotSupportComparisons : 0; }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass a;
    MyClass b;

    if(a && b) {}
}
```

Comment: It looks like VooDoo to me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler searches for the best match for **(a && b)**.

Because the class doesn't have an operator that turns **MyClass** to a boolean, it searches for the best cast.

**operator aaa() const** is a cast to an aaa type pointer. Pointers can be evaluated in an if sentence.

[Overloading typecasts](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/910-overloading-typecasts)

[Conversion Functions (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s5sk305%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: +1. Do you have a list of best match operators it may try in order?

Comment: There's a default hierarchy for implicit casting between primitives. (Easy to find on the web). For custom classes I think it goes like this: Check Class -> Check base classes -> Check best matching cast (shortest implicit cast route/sequence to required type)

Comment: That's why implicit casts are dangerous... The chosen cast sequence isn't guaranteed, and a loss of information may occur

Answer (score 3):

Your variables are used in an expression. The type itself does not have an operator&& defined for it, but it **is** convertible to a type (a pointer) that can be used in the expression. So the conversion operator is called.

Comment: So what is going on here? it converts the class to a ptr then a ptr to bool? i still need clarification why it does that or maybe a list of operator precedence (such as why go bool instead of ! instead of int instead of void* instead of void class::* instead of ....)

Comment: If the class had an `operator bool` that would be used. Now it doesn't, so an alternative is to use one user defined conversion and one implicit pointer-to-bool conversion. The compiler does that all the time. That this pointer is a pointer to member, is just to limit the possible implicit conversions to bool only.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a type cast operator. Oops, never mind, misread 'why is this operator called' for 'what is this operator called'

---

Ok, I tested your code and examined it some more. So operator aaa is a type cast to type aaa. Type aaa is a pointer to a *member* function of type void func(). ThisTypeDoesNotSupportComparisons is a function of type aaa. operator aaa gets called and returns the pointer to function.

I think it is called because the if allows to use pointers to functions as well. You can test if a pointer is NULL or not, and this is the closest the compiler can find, so if calls the operator aaa and tests if the pointer returned is zero.